# xsl:sort xsl:for-each sort 2 levels

Tags: xml, xslt

My XML:

```
<bands>
  <band bandname="AAABand"> </band>
  <band bandname="CCCBand"> </band>
  <band bandname="BBBBand">
    <album title="Third" year="2020">
      <track n="1" title="First"/>
      <track n="9" title="Nine"/>
    </album>
    <album title="First" year="2010"> </album>
    <album title="Second" year="2015"> </album>
  </band>
</bands>
```

My XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/bands">
    <xsl:for-each select="band">
      <xsl:sort select="@bandname" order="ascending" />
      <xsl:copy-of select="." />
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It sorts bands, but I need also sort albums by year attribute...
Plz, help me.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to do:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
  
<xsl:template match="/bands">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="band">
            <xsl:sort select="@bandname"/>
            <band bandname="{@bandname}">
                <xsl:for-each select="album">
                    <xsl:sort select="@year" data-type="number"/>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="." />
                </xsl:for-each>
            </band>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```